# Finding items in a queue that can be processed in parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, queue

I have a queue that I am currently processing on a single thread. It is critical that I process the items in order; however, there are circumstances that I will be able to process the items in parallel.

So lets say I have three `Person` objects and I have to build a profile for each person. All of there life events come in order and have to be sequentially analyzed or else the profile will be inaccurate. All of the life events for each `Person` arrive into the same queue (using a `BlockingQueue` capped at 1000 entries).

For the sake of clarity, lets just say the `Person` objects are Chris, Bobby, and Jason. There will be times where Chris will occupy the next 500 events in this queue, putting Jason and Bobby on hold until all of Chris's events are processed.

I considered giving each `Person` their own personal queue but there may be upwards to 300 `Person` objects at a given time and this might yield unexpected results. I also considered scanning the queue for other `Person`'s to start analyzing but doing this on every take might be way too many iterations.

What would be the best approach to this? Is there a queue implementation that already supports something like this?

Comment: Could you share some code regarding what you've already implemented? Also, regarding `I considered giving each Person their own personal queue but there may be upwards to 300 Person objects at a given time and this might yield unexpected results.`, what unexpected results are you thinking of? I think the question is currently a bit too vague to be easily answered.

Comment: Its not quite clear going thru the question(s). But, why not process Chris, Bobby and Jason's events in their own queues in separate threads? Is the application going to process 300 persons and 500 events each all the time?

Answer (score 0):

A queue per Person would be the best way to go, if we are talking about on-demand, in memory queues.

There might be optimization potential, but with those numbers you will likely not run into problems.